# Wilsonian renormalization group effective interactions

Tags: renormalization, effective-field-theory

**My current way of viewing wilsonian RGE applied to QFT:**

(1) We start with a lagrangian that accurately models dynamics up to a scale $\Lambda_0$.

(2) We fix $\Lambda_0$ as a cutoff to regulate the infinities characteristics to the infinite degrees of freedom of a QFT. This defines the theory dynamically.

(3) We define the theory numerically by choosing parameters (*e.g.*, couplings) in such a way that the predicted value for observables are consistently related to the observed results in a scale $\mu$, through some renormalization scheme.

(4) Then we chose to perform a sort of reparametrization, reversing the order of some operations, integrating an upper continuous subset of the energy degrees of freedom $(\Lambda,\Lambda_0]$, and redefining the original lagrangian so that the integral over this subset does not need to be done again and the cutoff from now on becomes $\Lambda$.

(5) We make sure that observables do not depend on where we are on 'the group', imposing that they do not depend on $\Lambda$, which, in turn, sets a dependence $g=g(\Lambda)$.

**Questions**:

**(i)** Is this correct -- or, at least, is this a right way to think of Wilsonian RGE? If not, what is wrong?

**(ii)** With the process of integrating out degrees of freedom (or coarse-graining, as some call it), the lagrangian changes and we end up with new effective interactions. This being the case, why do we only talk about the running of the couplings (in actual research, for instance, when looking for unification or on any field-theoretical study) without ever worrying about the new interactions? (ok, we worry about it a lot of times, but I do not understand why in a lot of situations we don't).

**(iii)** I have read, in a lot of texts, statements which I interpret as follows: if the cutoff is such that $\Lambda \gg M$, where $M$ is every relevant mass scale such as particle masses and $\sqrt{s}$ in a 2-particle collision, then the lagrangian remains the same after integrating out degrees of freedom. Why is this a good approximation? It is easy to accept it since most of the times the effective interactions are non-renormalizable and as such irrelevant and suppressed by $M/\Lambda$, but I'd like to really understand it.